# How do I set uploadReadAheadSize in HttpSelfHostConfiguration?

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Service using HttpSelfHostConfiguration
accept web requests.

Client is getting HTTP 413 error Request Entity Too Large

If this was happening in IIS, I'd fix it by setting
uploadReadAheadSize to something larger than 49k.

But what's the equivalent tweak for HttpSelfHostConfiguration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set MaxBufferSize and MaxReceivedMessageSize:

```
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(this._baseURI);
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Default",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        config.MaxBufferSize = 250000000;
        config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 250000000;
        this._server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was down voted. It was the solution for me   therefore -> up voted.. and.. he has answered his own question that he has asked ;-).